# Basic Calculating Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, calculator

I am looking to learn a few things with Ruby on Rails and was wondering how I can make a basic calculator that doesn't touch the model in rails.

I am using form_tag

This is my main page

```
<%= form_tag do %>
    <%= label_tag('first number') %> 
    <%= number_field('first_number', value = nil) %>
    </br>
    <%= label_tag('second number') %> 
    <%= number_field('second_number', value = nil) %>
    </br>
  <%= submit_tag("calculate") %>
<% end %>

<% first_number * second_number %>
```

I am getting an **error** that says :

```
undefined local variable or method first_number
```

How would I got about fixing this? I am not sure where to go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a controller method. Then in the form_tag give the method's url. Then receive the parameters in that method. Then calculate and show the result.

Suppose,
Your current view `calculator.html.erb` show the form.
in the form tag use `<form action="<%= calculate_result_path %>" method="post">`
Here, **calculate_result** is a method in any controller.

```
def calculate_result
   @result = params[:first_number] * params [:second_number]
end
```

Now make a view file for this method to show the result. Or you can ajaxify to show the result on the `calculator.html.erb` file.

***To Ajaxify***

suppose, you want to show the result in `calculator.html.erb` as like

```
<div class="show-result">
   <%= @result %>
</div>
```

now create a `calculate_result.js.erb` for the method `calculate_result`. On that JS file replace the **div** with class **show-result** using a custom **div** where you put your result which you get from the controller method.

To learn more about, please learn how to ajaxify your views in rails. I'll recommend you to read the book "[Agile Development](https://pragprog.com/book/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails-4)"

Comment: How would the ajax iteration look like?